HSTS Configuration in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
Currently we are using the .NET Core 8.0 version and implemented the HSTS for our .NET Core service as shown in code snippet below. But we're unable to see the security header in API calls on our server.
When I run the service in local/dev env, I am able to see the Strict-Transport-Security header in the API call, but when try to call the same API in stage env, that same rule is missing from the API call. For local API call, I create the DNS name by modified the host file and make a call to API using https.
Please help to to resolve this.
I tried the run the service on local env and able to see the security header but not on stage:
enter image description here
// HSTS Security Headers 
services.AddHsts(options =>
     {
         options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
         options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
     });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHsts();  
}                                                                                                    


You can check if the web server in the environment has a proxy or load balancer configured, and whether they have any filtering or configuration for the HSTS header. If the project has a related Host subdomain configured, you can enable includeSubDomain, which will apply the HSTS policy to the Host subdomain. You can refer to this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-sles#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts
